# SQL Server error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, datetime

When I am trying to execute this query.

> ```
> select    
>     DATEDIFF(HOUR, CONVERT(varchar(19), inputDate),
>     CONVERT(varchar(19), startingWork)) 
> from TICKET_LOG
> ```

it return a SQL Server error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

'17-10-2015 11:30:51' and  '12/4/2014 8:38:00 A' string

What is the error? Can anyone help me solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're converting it to a string, try:

```
select DATEDIFF(HOUR,CONVERT(datetime,inputDate),CONVERT(datetime,startingWork))
from TICKET_LOG
```

If you're still getting errors, it probably will involve that the date isn't in the required format. Have a look at the documentation to see the formats you can pass:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: it return this error  "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: You'll need to make sure the value you're inputting match the specified formats. I'll include a link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting your `DATETIME` values to string?? Absolutely no need to do that! Just use

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, inputDate, startingWork)
FROM
    TICKET_LOG
```

and all should be good.....

This assumes that `inputDate` and `startingWork` are both of datatype `DATETIME` - and since they seem to be expressing a date&time, that's what the *should be* !

Answer (score 0):

If you would have been using **2012** 
[TRY_CONVERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185931/sql-server-error-conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-charact) will help you to find solution to your answer , Unfortunately your's is 2008 so u need a function like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TryCastInt(@inputStr NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS int 
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret INT;
    SET @ret = -999999

        IF(ISNUMERIC(@inputStr) = 1)
            BEGIN
            IF(CHARINDEX('.',@inputStr) = 0 )
                Begin
                select @ret = cast (@inputStr AS INT)
                END
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
            set @ret = -999999
            END

    RETURN @ret;
END;
```

Now you can check wrong character pattern of your column.

```
SELECT *,
   dbo.TryCastInt(varchar(19), inputDate),
   dbo.TryCastInt(varchar(19), startingWork)
FROM 
    TICKET_LOG
```